# How do I remove the default ContextMenu while in edit mode on a treeview node?

Tags: c#

While in Edit mode of a treeview node.  When someone right clicks a context menu with cut, copy, paste, insert unicode character, among other items appear.  Cut, copy and paste would be ok but i do not want anything else to appear.

Is there a way to remove some or all of these items?

Comment: Obligatory, "Winforms or WPF?" question. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: This is a dynamically generated text box control, it has the same context menu as any other text box in Windows.  Changing it is quite difficult, you'll need TVM_GETEDITCONTROL to get a handle to it and sub-class it so you can catch the WM_CONTEXTMENU message.  Fixing that menu in any other program that runs on the user's machine is of course not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the IsEnabled property of the MenuItem to a property form the ViewModel or Code-Behind of the View and change the value of the property in case of WPF:

WinForms scanario: You could use the approach suggested in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol.aspx